# How To Interact With External Website Within WebPage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

From my web page I need to interact with an external website.  I want to automate the process of entering text in one field and pressing the submit button, then showing or getting the result.

I have tried using iframes and window.open and window.location.assign, etc., but in each case the external site comes up but i cannot access its document or interact with it.  I get "Access Denied" because of the XSS browser restriction.

On the server side, I have tried POST method to the site with a httpwebrequest and every other possibility on the client side, but the external website doesn't have query parameters in the URL nor a way to POST to it.  I have even tried the windows.forms.webbrowser control from the server side.

I think this is a dead end, but does anyone have a possible workaround or fresh new approach?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the external site is using raw java-script on it's form to collect the data and submit it to a server, in which case no amount of posting to the page in any shape would allow you to submit automatically. If the page were using java-script, potentially you could iframe it and talk to it through java-script, but without help from the site owner that may not work. it would be helpful if we could have the URL of the page inquestion

Comment: I think you are absolutely right.  It's a public site for tracking shipments:

http://www.shipmentlink.com/servlet/TDB1_CargoTracking.do

It requires that you enter a bill of lading #, then press Submit.  Then you get another page where there is a link to a particular container.  That leads you to the tracking page which is my goal to obtain.

But its the same on, for example, www.google.com, to enter a search term then press Search Google.  You can do this through parameters in the query strong on google, but not on above site.  Have already contacted them, they said "it was a good idea".

Comment: OK. So you could load the page into an iframe, hidden if you prefer. and access the form elements and buttons using  window.iframe.document.getElementsByid

Comment: Doesn't work.  In debugger, window.iframe.document.getElementsByTagName('input') shows me elements on MY web page not the page that is the src of the iframe.  window.iframe.contentWindow.document shows "Access Denied" because of cross-browser security.  That is the problem.

Comment: I think this question should be closed, since the site in question breaks cross browser security, no solution can be provided, but i think the solutions offered are good.